# Simpler way to test a list using an incrementing value (Python 2.5.X)

Tags: python, increment, pow

I'm working out of a book that teaches the principles of computer programming through Python. One of the finger exercises asks that I: *Write a program that asks a user to input an integer and prints two integers, root and pwr, such that 0 < pwr < 6 and root^pwr is equal to the integer entered by the user. If no such pair of integers exists, it should print a message to that effect.* I wrote a program that does what this asks. I just have one question about testing the equation with the numbers of a list. Here's my code:

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
root = 0
pwr = [1,2,3,4,5]
listnum = 0

for root in range(0, x + 1):  
    while pow(root, pwr[listnum]) < x:
        root += 1
        if pow(root, pwr[listnum]) == x:
                print str(root) + '^' + str(pwr[listnum]) + ' = ' + str(x)
                break
        listnum += 1
        if pow(root, pwr[listnum]) == x:
                print str(root) + '^' + str(pwr[listnum]) + ' = ' + str(x)
                break
        listnum += 1
        if pow(root, pwr[listnum]) == x:
                print str(root) + '^' + str(pwr[listnum]) + ' = ' + str(x)
                break
        listnum += 1
        if pow(root, pwr[listnum]) == x:
                print str(root) + '^' + str(pwr[listnum]) + ' = ' + str(x)
                break
        listnum += 1
        if pow(root, pwr[listnum]) == x:
                print str(root) + '^' + str(pwr[listnum]) + ' = ' + str(x)
                break
        listnum = 0
    if pow(root, pwr[listnum]) == x:
        break
    else:
        print 'No combinations within parameters exist'
```

I'd like to know how to test *if pow(root, pwr[listnum]) < x* for all 5 increments without having to repeat *listnum += 1...if...break* repeatedly. If the question is unclear I can try to elaborate more. I've seen a question regarding this exact problem, but none of them clearly answer the specific question I have, so I have no intention of reposting a question. If any other suggestions are to be made, they are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First note that `pwr[listnum] == listnum + 1`, so there's really no need for the `pwr` list.  You could instead iterate over `range(1, 6)` (which is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you're after:

```
def find(x):
    for root in range(x + 1):
        for pwr in range(1, 6):
            y = pow(root, pwr)
            if y > x:
                break
            if y == x:
                return root, pwr
    return None

x = int(raw_input('Enter an integer: '))
result = find(x)
if result is None:
    print 'No combinations within parameters exist'
else:
    root, pwr = result
    print root, "**", pwr, "=", x
```

I'm not sure that's what you *do* want, though.  `^` in Python is bitwise exclusive-or, not exponentiation.  So it's peculiar that the problem statement used `^`.

Another peculiarity is that `"No combinations ..."` will never be printed, because no matter what you enter for `x`, `pow(x, 1) == x` will be found as a solution.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This worked out much better. I, being new to Python, wrote root^pwr out of habit instead of root**pwr, which is printed in the book. As for the error message it asked me to print, I think that is strange too, maybe it just got overlooked or trying to get new programmers into the habit of having an alternative to conditionals.